# String splitting according to symbol python

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, split

How to split a string according to appearance of certain symbol?
Specifically (,),+,-,*,/
Example:

```
'a','bc+d' -> 'a','bc','+','d'
'(abcd)' -> '(','abcd',')'
'a','+','b' ->  'a','+','b'
```

RESTRICTION: use of regex forbidden!

Comment: making new list and filling it, but i have problem realising what is the lenght between two special symbols to insert it in new list

Comment: Are you trying to create a simple calculator? If so, you'll probably need to create a parser rather than just splitting the string with operators.

Comment: Could you please show code, along with inputs and expected and actual outputs (or full error traceback)?

Comment: @RubyHora Your strings are confusing...

Comment: Whats confusing? I just want to split strings that are written wrong. String into list of strings according to symbols
'i*i*i' ->'i','*','i','*','i'
'a+bccdcdcd-34' -> 'a','+','bccdcdcd','-','34'

Comment: do you mean separate letters, numbers and symbols?

Comment: not exactly, 'ab434+ a' -> 'ab434','+','a'... I just want to split string if any of (,),+,-,*,/ happen

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split()` to spit a string based on some patter.

Here the pattern should be

```
[\(\)\+\-\*\/]
```

the code may look like

eg.

```
re.split('[\(\)\+\-\*\/]','a+b')
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Limited not to use regex